# Ubuntu + Ember not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ember.js, ubuntu-14.04, ember-cli

I have node 0.12.0 installed, I installed it using NVM.
I have ember-cli installed, I have it using npm:
I installed it by:
sudo npm install -g ember-cli

Now though, when I try and run ember server on a brand new ember project, it makes me get 100s of modules, I have been doing it for about half an hour and using npm to install each module by hand. Is their a better way to do this, because this is a pain?

As well, I cant seem to get the node/debug module, so I am a bit stuck.

```
arie@arie-UX32VD:~/Desktop/programming/git/bostonember/ember$ sudo npm install debug/node
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node Cloning into bare repository '/home/arie/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-debug-node-65a3e6d9'...
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:debug/node and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install debug/node
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'debug/node'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-34-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "debug/node"
npm ERR! cwd /home/arie/Desktop/programming/git/bostonember/ember
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path debug/node
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/arie/Desktop/programming/git/bostonember/ember/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: The command `npm install node/debug` attempts to install the debug repo from the user node on github.com which doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you do `ember init project-name` to create an ember project?

Comment: No I did not, I have been just writing ember new projectName. How should I do it?

Comment: they both do the same thing, that's fine

Comment: you shouldn't install npm packages with sudo

Comment: But it tells me to retry as the super user when I install packages without sudo? I dont get what I am doing wrong, any tips on how to actually set this up?

Comment: Thats probably because you ran `ember init` with sudo too. Keep at it! Try starting all over. `ember init` should install every npm module you need to start. after that you can run `ember serve` and you can go to http://localhost:4200/.

Comment: It immedietely says can't find module chalk, and then if I install that it says it cant find something else!! Ahhhh I am not using sudo when writing ember new

Comment: cd into the project directory and run `npm install` and `bower install` they will install all the needed dependencies. It should do this during '`ember new`, but perhaps it failed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused because you have multiple versions of Node in your system. You installed it through `nvm` and probably you also have Node installed through `apt-get`, the later is the one that asks about `sudo` permissions, `nvm` would never do that.

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

Completely remove node from your system and only use the binaries installed by `nvm`. You can verify that you are using the correct binaries with:

```
which node
```

expected output:

```
~/.nvm/v0.12.00/bin/node
```